# I want to execute showBottomSheet with animation, but the sheet is not being displayed. Could you please give me some advice?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to use the animated showBottomSheet function with the onPressed property of multiple button widgets.
I tried implementing an animated showBottomSheet, but the bottom sheet is not being displayed, and the process is ending without any error. When I debugged the code, it stopped at the following part.

```dart
class CustomShowBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomShowBottomSheet({super.key, required this.mainWidget});
```

How can I display a bottom sheet with animations? If you have any advice, please let me know. Thank you.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'custom_show_bottom_sheet.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: TextButton(
      onPressed: () => CustomShowBottomSheet(
        mainWidget: Container(height: 200, color: Colors.amber),
      ),
      child: const Text('show'),
    )));
  }
}
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomShowBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomShowBottomSheet({super.key, required this.mainWidget});

  final Widget mainWidget;

  @override
  State<CustomShowBottomSheet> createState() => _CustomShowBottomSheetState();
}

class _CustomShowBottomSheetState extends State<CustomShowBottomSheet>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController animationController;
  static final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      reverseDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: showCustomBottomSheet,
        child: widget.mainWidget,
      ),
    );
  }

  void showCustomBottomSheet() {
    showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
   
        return SlideTransition(
          position: Tween<Offset>(
            begin: const Offset(0, 1),
            end: Offset.zero,
          ).animate(animationController),
          child: widget.mainWidget,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Onpressed event should be method call/action and should not return Widget.

You need to call `showCustomBottomSheet()` method in `onPressed` event.

make `showCustomBottomSheet` method as static and call

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () => CustomShowBottomSheet.showCustomBottomSheet(),
      ));
}
```